# How to add extra text to input value result using jQuery

Tags: jquery

My html form is:

```
<form id="search" action="form.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="keyword" name="search" placeholder="keywords" />
</form>
```

When type "test" and hit enter, it will go to **form.html?search=test**

Using jQuery, how can I add "xx-" on the result, i.e. **form.html?search=xx-test** ?

Thank you

Comment: What is your goal? Can you include your attempt in using jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: The site I'm working on has hard-coded search result page **/search?search=xx-keyword**. And my goal is to use static html form to pass the input value to the search page. It would be easy if it doesn't have **xx-**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$("#search").submit(function(event) {
  var $form = $( this ),
      url = $form.attr( 'action' );
  var submitdata = $.get( url, { search: "xx-" + $('#keyword').val()} );

  submitdata.done(function( data ) {
    alert('success');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `keypress` to catch enter event and make your url to redirect like this.

```
$('#keyword input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        var keyword= $('#keyword').val();
        window.location = form.html?search=xx_' + keyword;
    }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the submission of the form, and construct the URL by yourself.

```
<form id="search" action="form.html" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="keyword" name="search" placeholder="keywords" />
</form>
<script>
$("#search").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.attr('action')
  url += '?keyword=xx-' + encodeURIComponent($('#keyword').val());
  location.href = url;
});
</script>
```